# Haskell: how to test that assertion exceptions are raised by a lifted function, using Tasty & Hspec

Tags: haskell, monads, assert, hspec, tasty

I'm very much still a beginner at Haskell. I learn best by trying things out, but sometimes I feel like I'm missing something fundamental. This is one of those times.

I have some code that calls `Control.Exception.assert` but the Assertion exception wasn't being thrown. I tracked this down to asserts being ignored by default (which is unusual since the docs suggest the opposite), so I added this to my `package.yaml`:

```
library:
  ghc-options:
    - -fno-ignore-asserts
```

I'm not using `-O1` or `-O2` or `-fignore-asserts` so I don't know why the default behaviour is to ignore `assert`, but that's not what this question is really about.

I want to write an Hspec unit test to check this behaviour (and also as a chance to learn a bit about Hspec).

In my `Lib` module:

```
-- Lib.hs
module Lib (checkAssert) where

import Control.Exception

checkAssert :: Bool
checkAssert = assert (1 == 2) False
```

This module is compiled with `-fno-ignore-asserts`.

And in my `Spec.hs` (I'm actually using Tasty to host the tests):

```
import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.Hspec
import Lib
import GHC.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import qualified Control.Exception (assert, AssertionFailed)
import Control.Monad

assertionException :: Selector Control.Exception.AssertionFailed
assertionException = const True

-- Hspec tests
spec_assertRaises :: Spec
spec_assertRaises = do
  it "assert" $ (liftM checkAssert) `shouldThrow` assertionException

unitTests :: TestTree
unitTests = testGroup "Lib Unit Tests"
  [ -- add Hspec tests to Tasty TestTree
    unsafePerformIO (testSpec "spec" spec_assertRaises)
  ]

main :: IO()
main = defaultMain unitTests
```

This test module is not compiled with `-fno-ignore-asserts`. I think this is OK because it doesn't actually call `assert` itself, it just calls the function `checkAssert` in the `Lib` module, which *is* compiled with that flag.

The problem I'm having is actually related to how non-monadic functions are called from Monads like `Spec`. From my reading, I can use `fmap` or `liftM` to call a non-monadic function like `checkAssert` - but I'm not able to get this to compile:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a10 -> r0’ with actual type ‘Bool’
• In the first argument of ‘liftM’, namely ‘checkAssert’
```

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong with this, please?

Note: I became aware that [`Test.HUnit.Tools`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/testpack-2.1.3.0/docs/Test-HUnit-Tools.html) has `assertRaises` and I initially tried to use this instead, but `Test.Tasty.HUnit` does not include this function for some reason.

Comment: The type of `liftM` is `Monad m => (a -> r) -> m a -> m r`. It takes a function and a monadic action, and applies the function to the action's result. `checkAssert` is not a function.

Comment: When you say that `checkAssert` is not a function, what do you mean exactly? Does a function always need to take at least one parameter? What is it if it's not a function? If I changed `checkAssert` to `checkAssert :: Bool -> Bool` `checkAssert x = assert (1 == 2) x` would that be sufficient?

Comment: In your code, `checkAssert` has type bool `Bool`. Only values with at type like `something -> otherthing` can accept parameters (which must be of type `something`). I'm usure about possible solutions because I don't know the type of `shouldThrow`. Aslo, an unrelated tip: instead of using that `unsafePerformIO`, it would look better if you did something like `x <- testSpec "spec" spec_assertRaises` in a do-block inside your `main`, and then constructed the `TestTree`  in a `let` in the do-block, before invoking `defaultMain unitTests`.